# How to convert a JPA native query to stream of record classes

Tags: java, jpa, java-stream, record

I have a database with a stored procedure, so I need to use a JPA native query to include that in the output. I would like to put the result of the query in a Java record class and then process that using streams.

```java
    record Consistof(Integer articlenr, String articleDescription, String articletypeDescription, String locations) {}
    
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT ... ").getResultStream()
    .map(values -> {
        Object[] oa = (Object[])values;
        return new Consistof((Integer)oa[0], (String)oa[1], (String)oa[2], (String)oa[3]); 
    })
    .forEach(consistsof -> {
        System.out.println("!!!!!" + consistsof);
        //System.out.println("!!!!!" + consistsof.articlenr());
    });
```

When I run the code above, the output shows instances of the record class. So the mapping is correct and working. However, the compiler feels that I cannot uncomment the last line; it does not recognize the articlenr() method. Why?

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method articlenr()
  location: variable consistsof of type java.lang.Object
```

Comment: It works correctly if I collect the result after the map into a list and then stream over that again.

Comment: Could not reproduce the issue after uncommenting the line with `articlenr()` getter.  Please make sure that the name is typed correctly.  You may also provide the sample of current output.

Comment: I copied the actual code, so the articlenr in de record matches the one in the commented line. Maybe it is a difference between the Eclipse compiler and the normal JDK... It's the Eclipse compiler that complains.

Comment: No, also the OpenJDK compiler has issues with this: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method articlenr()
  location: variable consistsof of type java.lang.Object